# No mutually perpendicular line between z-axes, are there still valid D-H Parameters?

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, dh-parameters

I am trying to set up a generalized approach to generate DH parameters for my simulated robot arms, but I am having trouble setting up the frames. To find the X axis of each joint I read that I have to find a line orthogonal to both Z axes of the previous and current joint.
e.g. as explained in this video around 0:40 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rA9tm0gTln8

However, in some cases I find that a line orthogonal to both Z axes does not seem to exist. So how do I then determine the X-axis direction of subsequent joints. Are there configurations for which DH-parameters simply do not exist? or is there some other rule tied to this? Or does this orthogonal line exist somewhere but I'm simply failing to find it?
I can't find my specific case online. I have enclosed a picture with the two Z axes drawn in the axis of revolution for 2 joints. the Z axes are not intersecting anywhere, not parallel and not perpendicular.[image: two joints with Z axes pictured in axis of rotation]

Comment: DH is not unique. Which one you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Given two linearly independent (read: not parallel) vectors, you can always find a vector which is perpendicular to both of them using the cross product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  Depending on which version of D-H you are using, look at the $d$ and $r$ terms to accommodate the offsets.